# How to calculate total transfer size of a page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to calculate the total transfer size of a webpage, as it is shown in the Network tab of the browser dev tools:

[image]

In order to achieve that, I'm trying to use the `window.performance` API. However, I get different values from what the browser says.

Here is my script to calculate the total transfer size:

```js
  const getTransferSize = () => {
    let totalTransferSize = 0;

    performance.getEntriesByType('resource').map((resource) => {
      const data = resource.toJSON();
      totalTransferSize += data.transferSize;
    });

    return totalTransferSize;
  };

  console.log(`${bytesSent / 1024 / 1024} MB`); // This returns 1.5MB instead of 2.7MB
```

Any idea why I'm not getting the full transfer size?

Would there be another way to calculate this?
Maybe server-side using nodejs?

Thanks!

Comment: What when you disable the cache? On my side I've got the impression that cached responses's headers still do increment the dev-tools counter but are ignored by the Performance API. Also, it seems Chrome's log is really in MB and not in MiB. Oh and do you have cross-origin resources in there? They won't appear in the Perfs API.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. When I empty the cache and refresh the page, I get 157KB via the Performance API, and the browser says 1.3MB ; 
Then if I open the page in a new tab, the Performance API says 0B, but the browser now shows 1.2MB. So I guess only my js files are cached, but what are the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have full access to network traffic. Hence, your script could not catch all the requests. It only catches the javascript-related resources. You may find your solution on nodejs side. Here is a related post for nodejs. [node.js calculating bandwidth usage by domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100060/node-js-calculating-bandwidth-usage-by-domain)

Comment: Oh ok, this is good to know! Unfortunately I'm not able to work with the link you provided (the examples are pretty old). Anyway, I'm working with NextJs, so I can do some stuff on the server side, so I'll explore further in that direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so actually I found that the browser extensions where included in the transfer  size of the network tab.
So for anyone wondering the same, simply open the website in private navigation to get more accurate results!